# Filtering by nested object values in powershell when boolean value is present

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I'm running into a problem where I can't efficiently filter objects based on their nested objects' values when there is a boolean value present.

Take the following objects where I want to find out which object is the laptop.

```
id name    fields                                                                                                                
-- ----    ------                                                                                                                
 1 device1 {@{id=1; label=ip address; value=192.168.0.1}, @{id=2; label=type; value=Computer}, @{id=3; label=active; value=True}}
 2 device2 {@{id=4; label=ip address; value=192.168.0.2}, @{id=5; label=type; value=Laptop}, @{id=6; label=active; value=True}}
```

Normally I would use where-object

```
$laptop = $devices | where-object {$_.fields.value -eq "Laptop"}
```

Unfortunately that returns *both* devices. It took me a while to figure out why, but it's because of the $true value in the 'active' fields objects.

Alright. So I tried filtering it further:

```
$laptop = $devices | where-object {$_.fields.value -eq "Laptop" -and $_.fields.label -eq "type"}
```

That doesn't help at all. Same result. Returns every object that has a "true" value somewhere.

So I tried this, which lets me get the right field value:

```
$laptop = $devices | select-object -expandproperty fields | where-object {$_.label -eq "type" -and $_.value -eq "laptop"}
```

That doesn't help me because I need to know the top level object. More specifically, the top object's id value.

I learned I can retain a property of the original object and still filter down with:

```
$laptop = $devices | select-object -property id -expandproperty fields | where-object {$_.label -eq "type -and $_.value -eq "laptop"}
```

The above throws this error because the property "id" exists in the child objects as well:

> select-object : The property cannot be processed because the property "id" already exists.

I ultimately was able to accomplish my goal by using ridiculous nested foreach statements layer by layer, but it's been making my brain bleed and seems horribly inefficient at scale.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Second sentence. "Take the following objects where I want to find out which object is the laptop."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new objects from the `fields`, which will make it easier to filter:

```
$deviceRecords = $devices |ForEach-Object {
  # copy the id and name property values to a new ordered dictionary
  $properties = [ordered]@{
    id   = $_.id
    name = $_.name
  }

  # copy each of the field values to the dictionary
  $_.fields |Sort-Object id |ForEach-Object {
    $properties[$_.label] = $_.value
  }

  # output a new output with the properties described in the dictionary
  [pscustomobject]$properties
}
```

Now all you have to do to find the laptop(s) is:

```
$deviceRecords |Where-Object type -eq Laptop
# or 
$deviceRecords |Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'Laptop' -and $_.active}
```

Comment: I learned a lot from that. Worked perfectly!